# What does “straight out of [person]” mean?

Tags: meaning, idioms, prepositions

I know the meaning of the *straight out*. But what does it mean with *of*? 
For example:

> It’s straight out of Alice Miller.

Comment: From the horse's mouth. http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/straight_from_the_horse's_mouth

Comment: Context? "Alice Miller" here could be referring to the works/ thinking of the psychologist Alice Miller -- "née Alicija Englard ... noted for her books on parental child abuse.... Her book *The Drama of the Gifted Child* caused a sensation and became an international bestseller with the English publication in 1981. Her views on the consequences of child abuse became highly influential. In her books she departed from psychoanalysis, charging it with being similar to the poisonous pedagogies." http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alice_Miller_%28psychologist%29

Comment: @BlessedGeek With influential thinkers, philosophy has a stronger personality than the individual.

Comment: user77755, you need to click and edit your profile to an actual user name (ie nickname).  people don't like answering "usernnnn" users.

Comment: Why the close vote?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In short, *straight out of someone* means *characteristic of the works of someone*.

If I said

> I had an experience **straight out of Stephen King**.

I would mean an experience that could have easily taken place in a Stephen King novel. Since Stephen King is a very well-known horror writer, I’m saying the experience was absolutely terrifying (and possibly otherwordly).

Similarly, if I said

> She’s like a character **straight out of Ayn Rand**.

I might be implying she is selfish and narcissistic to the point of being a caricature, because the characters in Ayn Rand’s novels [and her real life...] were ridiculously self-absorbed.

Or, if I witnessed a streetfight, and when retelling the story, wanted to emphasize its violence, I might say

> It was a scene **straight out of Tarantino**.

Thus, *straight out of Alice Miller* might be read as *a **textbook case** of neglect and child abuse*. In [*The Pain and the Itch*](http://books.google.com/books?id=nRrdXlgkbJMC&pg=PA58#v=onepage&q&f=false), for example, one character (Kelly) says:

> No, it’s **straight out of Alice Miller**: neglect alternating with sarcasm.

Comment: Note for user7 - in **other** situations, in particular it can mean "was copied", "is derivative".  so you might say "that guitar riff is straight out of 'stairway to heaven'..." ie, the riff is copied, "lifted" from jimmy page playing in 'stairway to heaven'.  Dan explains it perfectly here, of course: something along the lines of "it's just like in _ _ _" or "it's a cliché as in _ _ _"