# Is "straight from Kafka" an idiom?

Tags: phrases, idioms, sentence, translation

I am working as a translator and in one of my projects, which was about strategic management , I came across this sentence:

> " In scenarios that come straight from Kafka, the simplest problems take months, even years to address."

Could someone please tell me what this sentence means or at least simplify it? Is the phrase "in scenarios that come straight from Kafka" an idiom??

Comment: I think this is General Reference. Although not many dictionaries will have an entry for ***Kafka***, they should all have [**Kafkaesque**](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/kafkaesque) - *used to describe a situation that is confusing and frightening, especially one involving complicated official rules and systems that do not seem to make any sense* (that definition's from the Oxford ***Learner's*** Dictionary). And if I google **define kafka**, four of the first five results point me to definitions for that derived adjectival form.

Comment: It's not an idiom. It's a cultural reference. The reader is supposed to know about Kafka's writing (oversimplified, about regular people having to dealing with absurd circumstances, especially government bureaucracy).

Comment: @FumbleFingers: It's a stretch to ask someone to go from "straight from Kafka" to *Kafkaesque* automatically. You're asking someone who may not know that unusual word to automatically think of it. Easy to do once you know the answer; not so much if you don't.

Comment: @Robusto: I understand what you mean, but the fact that the vast majority of Google results for **define kafka** actually have **Kafkaesque** as the *first word in the "snippet view"* is enough for me to say I think that's not a significant stretch *in context*. And if you consulted a paper dictionary, you'd obviously find it by going to the right place in the alphabetic sequence.

Comment: @Fumble: Plenty of questions we've all answered here are discoverable within one or two links of a Google search. Does that mean we should shut down the site? This question is about the meaning of that term and its suitability for use with a general audience. I don't call that off topic.

Comment: Related: [What does "*Straight out of <someone>*" mean?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/189660/55623)

Comment: Everyone seems focused on Kafka and "Kafkaesque," but I wonder if the question isn't inspired by the use of "come straight from" + a person's name (standing in - in this particular case - for the realms depicted in his novels). Scenarios don't typically "come" from places (they don't move or travel at all). And "come straight from" is, in fact, a fairly strong collocation when used figuratively to mean "be reminiscent of."

Comment: @Robusto: If you think part of ELU's purpose is to help people who don't understand words like *Dickensian, Orwellean, Marxist, Rubenesque*, I suppose that's your prerogative (it's a user-generated content site, so any and all users get a say in the *scope* of that content). But ***I*** call it Off Topic.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: let's not be so quick to assume that it's the "Kafka" that prompted the question! I'd love to hear from the OP on this, but I normally assume that ELU users are adept googlers, so provision of doubt's benefit leads me to think that the OP is not simply asking us who Kafka was (and what the derived adjective denotes; indeed, the OP didn't even ask about "Kafkaesque"). There's more going on here than an irresponsible user looking for basic information.

Comment: @Rusty: I can go with that. In which context, I've no problem upvoting Centaurus's answer (which simply explains the *classification* of the usage, not the meaning). But I stand by my closevote because the OP specifically asks for the *meaning* as well as asking whether it's an "idiom".

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I suppose what mystifies me are attempts to close questions that are of evident interest to users (gauging by answers and comments and upvotes - and from established users, to boot). I mean, the site is for... the users, n'est-ce pas?

Comment: @Rusty Tuba: I don't know if it was before your time here on ELU, but *lots* of people were interested in the meaning of the Dalai Lama joke - *make me one [a pizza] with everything*. It was one of the most popular questions on the site, but it seems to have been completely erased now (with my rep, I can see ordinary "deleted" questions, but not that one). Being "of evident interest" doesn't automatically imply "on topic for ELU".

Comment: That is true. But there is a slippery slope when it comes to closing questions, and we must wear appropriate footwear.

Answer (score 13):

"in scenarios that come straight from Kafka" is not an idiom, and I will leave the matter of Kafka and cultural reference to others, but I think your question is a reasonable one and I'd like to point out that the phrase in question actually contains something that can be used idiomatically, in a sense, and that is the following ***phrasal template:***

> "come straight from"
>
> as in "X comes straight from Y."

The meaning can either be **literal** (indicating actual "coming") **or figurative** (in which case the meaning is like "be reminiscent of" or "seem to be derived from"). Let's start with some literal examples:

> This letter **came straight from** the President.
>
> The box **came straight from** the warehouse.
>
> I **came straight from** work to see you today.

Then there are some examples that highlight the *seeming* to come from somewhere:

> This pizza is so good it could have **come straight from** Italy.
>
> Your car looks like it **came straight from** the factory.

And then here are some figurative examples:

> Don't take that course; the professor **comes straight from** hell.
>
> The scenarios **come straight from** Kafka.
>
> Life's sweetest gifts **come straight from** the heart.

I hope that this has addresses the root of your question.

I recommend the following fascinating reading around the entire issue of phrases and idioms:

*[Difference between phrase and idiom](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/16343/difference-between-phrase-and-idiom)*

*[What exactly is an idiom?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/194130/what-exactly-is-an-idiom)* (with a fascinating post by @pavja2)

Also, for good reading on the pervasiveness of figurative or metaphorical language in  everyday speech and writing, check out *Metaphors We Live By*, by George Lakoff and Mark Johnson

Comment: An excellent (actual) answer  :)

Answer (score 11):

It's not an idiom, it's a literary reference. Saying something comes "straight from Kafka" implies it is dark and disturbing to the point of being surreal.

Franz Kafka was a Bohemian (Czech) writer who wrote strange stories of the grotesque and terrifying. In his most famous, *Metamorphosis*, the protagonist is inexplicably transformed into a gigantic bug overnight, and has to deal with the fallout from that.

We even have an adjective to describe this sort of thing: *Kafkaesque*. Here's what Wikipedia has to say about that:

> Kafka's writing has inspired the term "Kafkaesque", used to describe concepts and situations reminiscent of his work, particularly Der Process and "Die Verwandlung". Examples include instances in which bureaucracies overpower people, often in a surreal, nightmarish milieu which evokes feelings of senselessness, disorientation, and helplessness. Characters in a Kafkaesque setting often lack a clear course of action to escape a labyrinthine situation. Kafkaesque elements often appear in existential works, but the term has transcended the literary realm to apply to real-life occurrences and situations that are incomprehensibly complex, bizarre, or illogical.

I suppose if we have an adjective, that would imply some kind of idiomatic usage. It's a fine point. But since people who don't have enough literary background aren't likely to understand "Kafkaesque" except dimly, I don't think it would have enough currency to be a readily understood idiom for all readers.

Comment: For those who do not speak German, by *Der Process* and "Die Verwandlung", Wikipedia means *The Trial* and "Metamorphosis".

Comment: The Wikipedia entry misspells the German word for 'trial'. It is *Prozess* (previously *Prozeß,* before the orthographic reform of 1996).

Comment: Hi Robusto.  Could you actually address the question?  ie, **yes or no, is it a common phrase in English**.  there are two things you should do, (a) answer the question (ie, **yes or no, is it a common phrase in English** and (b), as a useful side issue, it's likely the OP does not know what "idiom" means so you should explain to the OP "idiom means a common phrase, you may be misunderstanding this".  The rest of your answer is a general essay on issues which involve the word "Kafka".

Comment: @JoeBlow: How kind of you to favor me with the One True Interpretation of what the question is looking for. And how thoughtful of you to further instruct me on how to answer a question. I hope there is no charge for your services.

Comment: No charge. (There's no convenient payment mechanism anyway.)

Comment: A Czech writer whose mother tongue was German, who also happened to have a Jewish background. So he was in some ways a minority in Bohemia (though, back then, less so of a minority than he would be today).

Comment: @ErikKowal Or possibly pre-1901 spelling I believe.

Answer (score 2):

The phrase *straight from Kafka* may not be an established idiom per se, but *in an X straight from Y* could be considered idiomatic. The phrase essentially means *reminiscent of* or *according to the school of*.

Check out this [excerpt from a ballet review](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/culture/theatre/dance/11218205/Triple-bill-Royal-Ballet-Covent-Garden-review-tremendously-beautiful.html):

> *The Age of Anxiety* is based upon the 1946 poem by W H Auden, depicting the lives of four New Yorkers who struggle to root themselves in a changing world. Scarlett places his dancers **in a set straight from Edward Hopper**, creates characters reminiscent of Tennessee Williams and Arthur Miller, and gives a nod to Gene Kelly that makes dazzling use of the virtuoso Steven McRae.

Or, in a [piece](http://www.armaghplanet.com/blog/space-shuttle-a-thirty-year-history-of-tragedy-and-triumph.html) documenting the work of NASA's space shuttle fleet:

> In 1998, Endeavour carried the first US module to the International Space Station (ISS). **In a venture straight from science fiction**, this was the first of dozens of flights to add components to the eventually vast complex.

Here, the writer isn't saying that the flight was fictional, but that it seemed so advanced at the time, that it almost resembled science fiction.

Or, in [this political piece](http://newsok.com/oklahoma-lawmakers-should-resist-push-to-repeal-common-core/article/3828361):

> **In a call straight from the John Kerry political leadership playbook**, Shannon was for Common Core before he was against it.

the writer is trying to point out that Shannon's "flip-flopping" is very similar to how John Kerry once famously justified his evolving opinion.

And from this [India news article](http://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/city/indore/Murder-accused-shot-dead-at-point-blank-range-in-government-hospital-bed/articleshow/38845637.cms):

> **In a scene straight from Bollywood flick**, stockily built killer entered the hospital in doctor's apron and a surgical mask, climbed stairs, and headed straight for bed number 17 on the third floor of 50-year-old hospital. Once there, the killer, whose identity is still not known, whipped out a pistol from apron and pulled the trigger.

Here, the reporter is saying that the event was so surreal it seems more fitting as the plot of an action movie than a real from an actual event.

Comment: Nice examples @J.R.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a sentence from [Wikipedia describing Kafka's novels](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Franz_Kafka#Works):

> Dark and at times surreal, the novel is focused on alienation, bureaucracy, the seemingly endless frustrations of man's attempts to stand against the system, and the futile and hopeless pursuit of an unobtainable goal.

Also [Kafkaesque](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Franz_Kafka#.22Kafkaesque.22) has become an adjective

> Kafka's writing has inspired the term "Kafkaesque", used to describe concepts and situations reminiscent of his work, particularly Der Process and "Die Verwandlung". Examples include instances in which bureaucracies overpower people, often in a surreal, nightmarish milieu which evokes feelings of senselessness, disorientation, and helplessness. Characters in a Kafkaesque setting often lack a clear course of action to escape a labyrinthine situation. Kafkaesque elements often appear in existential works, but the term has transcended the literary realm to apply to real-life occurrences and situations that are incomprehensibly complex, bizarre, or illogical.

You could rewrite the phrase as:

- in a scenario which seems like it could have appeared in one of Kafka's novels
- a scenario which reminds us of Kafka's novels
- a scenario which could have inspired one of Kafka's novels

Answer (score 0):

"Straight from Kafka" is a **metaphor**.

> metaphor - "a figure of speech in which a word or phrase literally denoting one kind of object or idea is used in place of another to suggest a likeness or analogy between them (as in drowning in money)" [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/metaphor)

Edit - No, "straight from Kafka" isn't an idiom. It's a figure of speech meaning that a certain scenario looks like situations found in that writer's works.

Answer (score 0):

An idiom is nothing more than **a very common** phrase or speech pattern.

The phrase you mention **is not** an idiom.

Merry xmas!

Comment: Do you mean like "Merry Christmas?" That's a very common phrase, but it is certainly not an idiom. The definition begs greater precision.

Comment: This is not a very useful answer without anything to back it up. If I were to post the answer "The phrase you mention **is** an idiom", how would anybody distinguish which of us was right?

Comment: Actually Chris, this is the one and only answer here, of any value. The rest just waffle on about, literally, totally unmentioned and unrelated issues (such as "Kafkaesque").  **By all means**, if someone was to either edit my answer to add references, or, just repeat my answer (ie, the only correct one - the only one that actually addresses the question) with more references that would also be great.  Note too that ESL questions like this (it's asking: "is this a common phrase in English") are all-but impossible to "find references for".  (How could you possibly, ever, find research and ...

Comment: ... references investigating the issue "is { that phrase } a common phrase in English?!"  It just doesn't make sense.  the best you can possibly do is have a few native speakers state whether or not it is common. This is a well known issue on this site.  (Of course, the best solution is to have the question eliminated since it's useless and off-topic, but that's a bit harsh on Xmas!  :) )